# how can i resize a pvc when my backend storage provider is "vsphere"?

Tags: kubernetes, vsphere, kubernetes-pvc, vcenter, storage-class-specifier

I created a pvc which uses vsphere as backend storage privider:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-world-logs
  namespace: mbe
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  storageClassName: vsphere
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

But when i am trying to resize the pvc in question to 2Gi, i got the following message:

```
Ignoring the PVC: didn't find a plugin capable of expanding the volume; waiting for an external controller to process this PVC
```

PS:
I added `allowVolumeExpansion: true` to my storage class object.
my k8s version : 1.18

What should i do to make it working ?

Any help would be really appriciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Does the vsphere storage provider have support for "resize"?

Comment: how can i know that ?

Comment: Have you checked the provider documentation?

Comment: yes, i saw this page : https://vsphere-csi-driver.sigs.k8s.io/features/volume_expansion.html , but i have not understood it very well

Comment: Does your storage class have `allowVolumeExpansion: true` ?

Comment: yes, i did it  (in storage class object)